# Notice: Undefined offset: 4

Tags: php

I'm working on my ticketing system project, there's an error on my code and I've already search on web some answer but nothing works. The error says

> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\wamp\www\Online Bus Reservation\admin\bussch.php on line 69

Here is my code

```
$ddaa = mysql_query("SELECT id, route, time FROM bus_sch ORDER BY id");
echo mysql_error();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($ddaa))
{
$sold = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM seat_details WHERE busid='".$data[0]."' AND status='1'"));
$available = $data[4]-$sold[0];
$rname = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT routename FROM bus_route WHERE id='".$data[1]."'"));
```

The Line 69 is:

```
$available = $data[4]-$sold[0];
```

Please Help. Thank you :)

Comment: `$data` doesnt have a fifth ([4]) index. Look at what it is, `print_r($data);`. You also should update your db driver (PDO or mysqli) and use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message:

```
Undefined offset: 4
```

And pay attention to your query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id, route, time FROM bus_sch ORDER BY id");
```

You have three element:

- 0 for id
- 1 for route
- 2 for time